# Unique infinite subsets of the integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity, integers

Edit: Great points on the comments. There is no *unique* set of unique infinite subsets of the integers. Is this a better question?

What is the largest possible cardinality of a set which is a set of unique infinite subsets of the integers, or to put it another way, a set of infinite subsets of the integers such that the intersection of any two subsets is empty?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say "the"?  For example, take $S_p=\{p^n:n\ge 1\}$, for each prime $p$ (and $S_0$ to be everything left over).

Comment: I'm not sure this question is well-posed? Once you write down any infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ this will dictate what possible subsets are left, so the "number of possible subsets" will depend on this first set you write down?

Comment: I don't understand the connection between "unique" infinite subsets and the intersection of all such subsets being equal.  Can you please clarify the question a bit?

Comment: Do you mean the intersection of all pairs of said subsets, or do you really mean the intersection of the intersection of all the subsets?

Comment: The word "unique" does not mean what you think it means. Was that a Google translation from your native language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what you're asking:

- The set of all *infinite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is the same cardinality as the set of *all* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, $2^{\aleph_0}$; this is because the set of finite subsets is countable.
- But since you talk about intersections, it sounds like you mean something else. It's still not clear - for instance, the set of *all* infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ has the property that its intersection is empty . . .
- but this is true for silly reasons: for instance, $\{$evens$\}\cap\{$odds$\}=\emptyset$, and so this stays true when we add more infinite sets to the collection. So maybe you're trying to ask something different.
- **Take 1**: maybe you want the intersection of the *whole* collection to be empty, but not *proper* subcollection. For instance, let $A_n=\{m: m>n\}$; then $\bigcap A_n=\emptyset$, but any finite intersection is nonempty (in fact, cofinite).
- **Take 2**: maybe you are asking about having *every* intersection be empty - that is, you want a family of sets $\{A_i\}$ such that $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ whenever $i\not=j$. Then clearly such a family can be at most countably infinite, since there are only countably many natural numbers in the first place. (Note that if we allow finite intersections, then we switch - there are continuum-sized families!)

Does this help?

Comment: Take 2. Thank you for your patience with my wording. I had guessed that the set was countably infinite, but my own wording of the set felt too close to a loose description of the power set of integers for my own novice comfort. My intuitions on the infinite still need training wheels.

Comment: @MichCon Glad to help! Note that this relies on the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-orderable; in the absence of the axiom of choice, we **can** in fact have a set $X$ and a partition $Y$ of $X$ which has "more" elements than $X$ does; see e.g. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22927/why-worry-about-the-axiom-of-choice/22935#22935.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is any family  of pair-wise disjoint subsets of $N,$ then for each $n\in N $ there is at most one $f\in F$ such that $\min f=n$. For $f\in F$ let $G(f)=\min f$ if $f\ne \phi$, and $G(f)=0$ if $f=\phi.$ Then $G$ is a bijection from $F$ to a subset of $N\cup \{0\}$ .So $F$ is countable. Example: For each prime $p$ let $f_p=\{p^n :n\in N\}$ and let $F=\{f_p :p$ prime $\}$.